# Same Custom web part feature not activated in Two Web application-Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint

We have created a custom web part and activated feature in web application .It is working fine
Now create a new web application and activate the web part feature
The custom web part is not working in previously created web application and error message is displayed as  "**The file you are attempting to save or retrieve has been blocked from this website by the server administrators**"

Note:Feature is activated in both web application

Comment: How was the web part deployed?

Comment: Deployed at the Web application level